# IAP Rejected because required binary was not submitted issue

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I have submitted an Unity(iphone) app with in-app purchase But my Binary is rejected.
I got the following message from apple:
"We have returned your in-app purchase products to you as the required binary was not submitted. When you are ready to submit the binary, please resubmit the in-app purchase products with the binary."
IAP work fine during testing on device. Submitted IAP has a screenshot and have been added to the submission before hitting the submit button.
I have shipped my build in android and working fine. In ios every thing is done expect IAP issue.I have changed productIdentifier many times but no success found.
Please help me find the solution.

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue getting my IAP products approved. There is no clear way to resubmit them once they are rejected, there is also no way to submit a build with you IAP products.(This might be fixed in the future)

This is the way I was able to get them approved:

1- In iTunes connect go to: Features -> In-App purchases and open the product that you want to submit. For me the status was "Developer action required". Once you open it, make some changes to the Localizations section and save the the IAP product, this should change the status from "Developer action needed" to "Waiting for review". You can revert the changes you made. (This step was suggested to me by apple)[image]

2- The second step is getting them to review the IAP subscriptions with the build you submit. Again there was no way for me to do so. So what I ended up doing is adding some notes to the "App Reviewer Information" section. Something like this:[image]

Comment: hi , In my case I have uploaded the first IAP with the new binary of my app. It got rejected and the reason they gave me that my app does not do anything on click of "Get premium " button. But as my first IAP was under review how can I actually use it to complete the flow of the payment feature. Can I use the under review IAP in my app for development purpose?

Comment: I had multiple IAPs, Changing name of 1 IAP made all IAP status to `Waiting for Review`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. Actually in my case i added the new version of app.I forgot to uplaod the binary for the new version & submitted the In App purchase for review. So they sent my In app purchase product back.

I did not change my In app purchase product. did the minor changes in the description and saved it.
I just uploaded the binary for Test Flight.